# Parse posted JSON string format in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to parse posted JSON content from android on PHP. My posted JSON content is:

```
{"username":"myName","password":"myPassword"}
```

and I'm try to parse it but my code doesn't work correct and I get `<br />` inside android.

What is going wrong? and How can I fix it?

**My code**

```
<?php
$entityBody1 = file_get_contents('php://input');
$entityBody = json_decode($entityBody1);
$test = [
    ['username'=>$entityBody->username,'password'=>'username'],
    ['username'=>'username','password'=>'username'],
];
/*
$test = [
    ['username'=>$entityBody1['username'],'password'=>'username'],
    ['username'=>'username','password'=>'username'],
];    
*/
echo json_encode($test);
?>
```

`var_dump` result is:

```
string(41) "{"password":"pishguy","username":"mahdi"}"
```

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Can you show us echo json_encode($test); output?

Comment: You'd better `var_dump($entityBody1)` to know what did you actually got there...

Comment: @Amarnasan post updated please review that

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ simply get json format, parse that and send again posted json

Comment: What "result" exactly are you var_dumping there? `$entityBody`? If `$entityBody` is a `string(41)` *after* json_decoding, that means you're probably sending a double-encoded JSON object in the first place. `var_dump` every value at every stage and be clear about what is what.

Comment: I ran your code and it did work flawlessly...

Comment: @mahdipishguy you wrote you get <br /> what is that related to what you asking for, we all would like to help, but we are confused a bit

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ thanks sir. my code is very simple, get username and password with json format and parse it on php and create simple array with that and convert to json.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your should set the assoc flag to true in order to make your array. associative

`json_decode($entityBody1, true)`

Comment: not correct and i get `<br />`

Comment: $res = json_decode($entityBody1, true); echo $res['username'];

Comment: thanks problem solved

Comment: who make down vote???? i'm up vote your post